# How to pass a variable (FilesToAdd) from VBA script (interface) to a Mapbasic program?

Tags: vba, mapbasic

```
Option Explicit

Public FilesToAdd As Integer

Private Sub TEST_Click()

FilesToAdd = 1

Dim b As Variant
Dim Prog As String
Dim File As String

Prog = "C:\Program Files\Mapinfo\Professional\Mapinfow.exe"
File = "C:\Mapinfo\Combine\SelectCarrier.MBX"

b = Shell(Path + " " + File, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't add extra parameters to your command line and then have your application reading these.

I can think of two options:

1. Write the value to a configuration file and let your MapBasic application read the value on startup
2. Transfer the value to the application using DDE. Have a look at the chapter "Inter-Application Communication Using DDE" in the [MapBasic User Guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/12.0/MapBasicUserGuide.pdf) (page 199)